# why my backtrace() only finds the path of a dynamic library

Tags: linux, dll, backtrace

```
void testfunc3(){
    char* funcname[20];
    int n = 0 ;
    n = backtrace((void**)funcname,20);
    char** p_need_free = (char**)backtrace_symbols((void**)funcname,n);     
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("funcname is : %s\n",p_need_free[i]);
    }
    free(p_need_free);
}
void testfunc2(){
    testfunc3();
}
void testfunc1(){
    testfunc2();
}
/** in another file **/
int main(){
    testfunc1();
    return 0;
}
```

> this project has 2 files , main() takes 1, other functions take
>   another, the latter file is compiled as a dynamic library.

Comment: The question is very difficult to read. Any chance you could reformat so it is easier to read?

Comment: First time using this web ,I am trying to format it, wait a minute .

Comment: anyone knows how to re-edit my question?

Comment: small grey edit links on the bottom left of your question ( share, edit, flag)